# google cloud datastore emulator exits with IOException

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, mocha.js

I have a 4 year old MacBook. I have been writing unit tests using mocha and the datastore emulator under WebStorm. The tests pass.

I recently acquired a new MacBook, so I used the Migration Assistant to transfer everything over to it. Everything works fine - except that when the unit tests try to start the datastore emulator it exits with an IOException: "Failed to bind"

I can run the emulator from the command line; it's only when calling DatastoreEmulator.start() from Mocha that it fails.

I've upgraded Java (just in case, as they were previously both running the same version) and updated gcloud. They are both using mocha 3.5.0
I cannot find any significant differences between the two machines. Rebooting does not help. There's nothing listening on the port - and I've tried using other ports.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve - or even debug - this issue I'd love to hear them. So far I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me, was a dummy problem. I was running the emulator and couldn't close with ctrl + C. So I closed the terminal and the process was stuck.
When I tried again to run the emulator, I received that same execption "failed to bind". It was because the port was already busy. Just sharing this if someone do the same as me.

Answer (score 0):

To debug I added Java debug flags to platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator (nothing else seemed to work) and connected to the process via Eclipse.

I found that it was trying to bind to localhost/192.168.1.1:8081 instead of localhost/127.0.0.1:8081

Eventually I traced this back to the fact that the previous user had erased /etc/hosts so localhost was no longer defined.